# using automapper to convert a number to a DateTime object

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to use automapper to convert the following values to an actual DateTime object.  I'm failing to get this working, is there anything I'm doing wrong?  Any help much appreciated

**Example values**

```
201503
201504
201505
```

**Objects shown below**

```
class DataObject 
{ 
    public int DateTime { get; set; }
}

class DomainObject
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

**Attempts so far with AutoMapper**

```
_mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(c => {
            c.CreateMap<DataObject, DomainObject>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.DateTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new DateTime(dest.SubString(0,4), dest.SubString(5,2), 1);
        });
```

**Compiler error**

```
compiler error actually, I get the following Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error CS0103  The name 'dest' does not exist in the current context..
```

**Second attempt**

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.DateTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new DateTime(src.Date.ToString().SubString(0, 4), src.Date.ToString().SubString(5, 2), 1)));
```

**Third attempt**

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.DateTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(src.Date.ToString().Substring(0, 4)), Convert.ToInt32(src.Date.ToString().Substring(5, 2)), 1)));
```

**Solution**

unfortunately I was getting bad data which was the underlying problem although the automapper code that works is shown below for closure.

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.DateTime, dest => dest.MapFrom(src => DateTime.ParseExact(src.DateTime.ToString(), "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
```

Comment: The second attempt looks much better - can you describe how that fails?

Comment: thanks! - It compiles but I get a run-timer error Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

Comment: The indexes are incorrect for the Substring. They should be Substring(0, 4) and Substring(4, 2).

Comment: yup I got that, thanks @momar!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your automapper `.ForMember` call:

> ```
> .ForMember(dest => dest.DateTime, 
>            opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new DateTime(dest.SubString(0,4), dest.SubString(5,2), 1);
> ```

You pass two lambda expressions. But use the parameter from the first lambda in the second. But lambda parameters are scoped to the lambda in which they are defined. (You can close over a variable in an outer scope, but these are sibling scopes so that does not apply).

I suspect you need to use `src` and not `dest` in the second lambda.

Comment: gone back to basics are I'm stilling getting problems actually, have tried the following .ForMember(dest => dest.DateTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new DateTime(2015, 1, 1)));

Comment: but I get this error Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Int32'.  It's as though the destination and source is back to front...(?)

Comment: @Jamie That's the next problem. That `DateTime` constructor takes `int` parameters, you're passing `string`s. Simplest (but least safe – unless you are checking the data elsewhere) is to use `Int32.Parse`.

Comment: @Jamie: Not the first lambda needs to be a very simple property/field selector: it just tells Auto Mapper which property/field you are setting. All the work of generating the value to set that property/field is in the second lambda.

Comment: You saved my day,
.ForMember(dest => dest.FirstServiceDate, m => m.MapFrom(a => new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(a.FirstServiceDate.Value.ToString().Substring(0, 4))
                                                                                                    , Convert.ToInt32(a.FirstServiceDate.Value.ToString().Substring(4, 2))
                                                                                                    , Convert.ToInt32(a.FirstServiceDate.Value.ToString().Substring(6, 2)))))